# For which $b$ it is possible that $S^n$ can have a Lorentz metric? Why?

Tags: spherical-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

It is possible that on a sphere $S^n$ there is a natural Riemannian metric in $R^(n+1)$. But it is not always possible for pseudo Riemann metric since the sum of two symmetric matrix which are not positive definite but may have rank different from the two matrix. So I wonder what is the sufficient and necessary condition for the dimension of a sphere which can be endowed with a Lorentz metric.

Comment: Manifolds have Lorentz metrics if and only if they have a section of the corresponding projective unit tangent bundle.  If you want details, please post to the math.stackexchange website listed in the FAQ as this is more of an upper-level undergraduate mathematics issue. 

Comment: If you don't want to post your question on math.stackexchange, take a look in the nearest manifolds textbook at the proof that abstract manifolds admit Riemann metrics (i.e. avoid proofs that use embeddings in euclidean space).  This is a paracompactness/bump function/partition of unity argument.  Now consider how you would perturb that proof for Lorentz metrics. 

Comment: @Ryan: should one understand that with a partition of unity argument you can show the existence of Lorenz metrics on every (paracompact) manifold? I have serious doubts about that...

Comment: @Andrei: it appears you did not read what I said in my first comment "Manifolds have Lorentz metrics if and only if they have a section of the corresponding projective unit tangent bundle".   

Comment: Andrei, I think Ryan is suggesting that when you try to adapt the proof for a Riemannian metric to a Lorentzian one, you run into anecessary condition for the Lorentzian metric to exist. Then you can check that the necessary condition is also sufficient.

Comment: Ryan, yes, I did not read the first comment, sorry. Still, the last sentence of your second comment was misleading.

Comment: I don't believe it is. My statement was that the proof is essentially identical to the Riemann metric case, once you adapt to the requirement of having a section of the projective unit tangent bundle.  Both are convexity arguments.

Comment: @Andrei, Ryan was right, he pointed out the key point of the problem in just take the proof of Riemannian metric to Lorentz metric. I noticed that but didn't get an idea of solving it. But still I wonder why it must take a section of the projective unit tangent bundle....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**A compact simply connected manifold carriez a Lorenz metric iff its Euler characteristic vanishes.**

Proof: If $\chi(M)=0$, $M$ carries a nowhere vanishing vector field $X$. Pick up a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ (using a partition of unity argument) and denote by $\eta$ the 1-form dual to $X$: $\eta(Y):=g(X,Y)$ for all $Y\in TM$. Then
$$g-2\frac{\eta\otimes\eta}{g(X,X)}$$
is a Lorenz metric.

Conversely, if $M$ has a Lorenz metric $h$ of signature $(n-1,1)$, pick again a Riemannian metric $g$ and consider the symmetric endomorphism $A$ of $TM$ defined by $h(.,.)=g(A.,.)$. The eigenspaces of $A$ corresponding to the unique negative eigenvalue define a line sub-bundle of $TM$ which is trivial if $M$ is simply connected, so $\chi(M)=0$.

Therefore, the answer to your question is: $S^n$ carries a Lorenz metric iff $n$ is odd.

Comment: Does this theorem have a name? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I would just like to point out that a slightly more general version of the statement in Moroianu's answer holds:

**A compact *orientable* manifold $M$ admits a Lorentzian metric if and only if $\chi(M)=0$.**

Clearly, simply-connected manifolds are orientable, hence the above statement is more general. But, e.g., tori clearly admit product Lorentzian metrics.

For the proof of the above statement, recall $M$ admits a semi-Riemannian metric of index $k$ if and only if the tangent bundle $TM$ admits a sub-bundle, or *distribution*, of rank $k$. Thus, $M$ admits a Lorentzian metric if and only if it admits a line bundle (which is also equivalent to $M$ admitting a vector field that never vanishes). The obstruction to the existence of a line bundle on $M$ is given by the Euler class of $M$ (see e.g. Davis and Kirk "Lecture notes in Algebraic Topology"). By the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem, the Euler characteristic is the Euler class evaluated on the fundamental class of $M$, so that, for compact orientable manifolds, the obstruction is precisely $\chi(M)$.