# Hitchin–Thorpe inequality for Lorentzian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity

I've recently read the following:

[For which $b$ it is possible that $S^n$ can have a Lorentz metric? Why?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44861/for-which-b-it-is-possible-that-sn-can-have-a-lorentz-metric-why)

An answer shows that a compact, oriented, simply connected manifold carries a Lorentz metric iff its Euler characteristic vanishes. Then by the Hitchin–Thorpe inequality I deduce that no compact Lorentzian manifold can be an Einstein space (since the signature is non zero for n>2)?

Surely this is not the case? (for example take de Sitter space over a finite world time interval).

Comment: The `signature' of an $n$-dimensional Lorentz manifold is not necessarily $n-1$. I think you're confusing the two notions of signature.

Comment: Is there a Hitchin-Thorpe inequality for Lorentz manifolds?  In particular, there is no $W=W^+ +W^-$ decomposition of the Weyl tensor used in the signature formula.